# Borel set as union of $G_\delta$ and countable set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

What is an example of a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$ which cannot be written as a union of a $G_\delta$ and a countable set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K\subset [0,1]$ be a Cantor set. Put $A=\mathbb Q+K$. Clearly, that the set $A$ is Borel. Assume that there exists a countable set $C\subset A$ such that a set $A\setminus C$ is $G_\delta$. Since the set $A\setminus C$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, the set  $\mathbb R\setminus (A\setminus C)$ is meager (that is a countable union of nowhere dense sets). Then the set $\mathbb R=A\cup \mathbb R\setminus (A\setminus C)=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q} (q+K)\cup\mathbb R\setminus (A\setminus C)$ is meager too, a contradiction with Baire theorem.

Comment: Why does it follow from $A\setminus C$ dense, that $\mathbb{R}\setminus (A\setminus C)$ is meager? (After all $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense but $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is not meager.)

Comment: @Achilles The set $A\setminus C$ is $G_\delta$. Let $A\setminus C=\bigcap G_n$ be an intersection of open sets $G_n$. Since $A\setminus C$ is dense, $G_n$ is dense for each $n$. Since $G_n$ is open, $\mathbb R\setminus G_n$ is nowhere dense. Then $\mathbb R\setminus (A\setminus C)=\bigcup \mathbb R\setminus G_n$ is meager.